# Convert Geometry to Geography

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, spatial-data

I want to convert geometry to geography in SQL Server; I followed this article:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edkatibah/2008/08/19/working-with-invalid-data-and-the-sql-server-2008-geography-data-type-part-1b/

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO gCOMMUNE         
SELECT 
      [dbo].[commune].[ogr_fid], 
      GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromWKB(commune.ogr_geometry.STAsBinary(),4326)
FROM [IMMATS].[dbo].[commune]
```

but when I ran the command to convert I got this error:

> **Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 The name or column number of the values provided does not match the definition of the table.**

Comment: The error message is pretty clear "The name or column number of the values provided does not match the definition of the table." What are the columns of `gCOMMUNE` table? Are they only 2 - first with the same type as `[dbo].[commune].[ogr_fid]` and the second to be `GEOGRAPHY`? If not, you must specify the column names where the data sould be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `gCOMMUNE` table has different number of columns than the query for selecting the data to be inserted in it. You must specify the column names in the [INSERT INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement. Assuming there are columns named `id` and `geom` (from your clarification it turns out they are [ogr_fid] and [ogr_geog]), here is how your statement could look like:

```
INSERT INTO gCOMMUNE([ogr_fid], [ogr_geog])
SELECT 
      [dbo].[commune].[ogr_fid], 
      GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromWKB(commune.ogr_geometry.STAsBinary(),4326)
FROM [IMMATS].[dbo].[commune]
```

Comment: please look at my comment below

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the real column names.

Comment: I use the request that you give me I get this error it is right

Comment: Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 26 A .NET Framework error occurred during the execution of the user defined routine or aggregation function "geography": System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values ​​must be between -90 and 90 degrees.

Comment: System.FormatException: at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeographyValidator.ValidatePoint (Double x, Double y, Nullable1 z, Nullable1 m) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.BeginFigure (Double x, Double y, Nullable1 z, Nullable1 m) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure (Double x, Double y, Nullable1 z, Nullable1 m) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.CoordinateReversingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure

Comment: Please don't add your errors as answers. You can edit your question. But the error message is clear - `Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.` so your data is not valid geography. Did you meant to use `geometry` instead?

Comment: I have a shapefile that contains the common of France I wanted to import  to my database sql server I did that with GDAL but I need  to convert to the geographic format I can not do that